# how to solve this error shown on eclipse for java?

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to run a hello world program for Java in Eclipse but it gives me an error to which I cannot find a solution, as shown below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:

system cannot be resolved
at myproject/myproject.MyClass.main(MyClass.java:6)
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Answer (score 1):

The first letter of `system` must be capitalized. Replace `system` with `System`.

Comment: thanks , i capiltalized the letter 's' and it worked:)